# zip files without any metadata

Tags: python, zip, metadata

I'd like to find an easy way to zip a bunch of files without any file metadata (e.g., timestamps). The `zip` command seems to always perserve the metadata. I don't see a way to disable metadata.

I'd like the solution be a command or at most a python script. Thanks.

Comment: See [`zipfile.ZipInfo`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo).

Comment: I don't see how to disable all the metadata. https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html

Comment: You can't - if you read through the links, you will see [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipInfo.date_time): The ZIP file format does not support timestamps before 1980.

Comment: My purpose is to ensure the resulted zip stays the same as long as the file contents are the same. If there is no way to eliminate the metadata field, maybe it is possible to always fill the same metadata that is never used in practice to achieve this goal?

Comment: Yes, that is why I referenced `ZipInfo` entry: your code will have to manually create these entries and add them to the `ZipFile` instance that your application/use case requires.

Comment: ZipInfo has many fields besides timestamp. What should their reasonable defaults that are invariant no matter where and when the zip file is created?

Answer (score 0):

As some of the posts have already pointed out most of the metadata fields in a zip header have to be present. If the file contents you are zipping are identical each time, then the only field that will be different is the timestamp.

It is possible to force the timestamp to be specific value by creating a `ZipInfo` object and changing the timestamp.

Here is a proof-of-concept

```
import zipfile

file = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip", "w")
name = "/tmp/testfile.txt"
zi = zipfile.ZipInfo.from_file(name)
zi.date_time = (1980,1,1,0,0,0)

with file.open(zi, mode='w') as member:
    with open(name, mode='rb') as file:
        fileContent = file.read()
        member.write(fileContent)
```

Above code creates `test.zip` with the field timestamp hard-wired to 1st Jan 1980.

```
$ unzip -l test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
      307  1980-01-01 00:00   tmp/testfile.txt
---------                     -------
      307                     1 file
```